# regexp. Как заменить все кроме шаблона?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
String line = "101@ext-local       : SIP/101,CustomPresen  State:Idle            Presence:not_set         Watchers  0";
System.out.println(line.replaceAll("^(\\w+/\\d+)","")); <- не работает
```

мне нужно получить SIP/101

Как?

Comment: Там может вам и не замена нужна, а просто матчинг?

Comment: matches возвращает boolean ... или вы про что?

Comment: Я java не знаю, но вот, например: http://www.javenue.info/post/43 find+group

Comment: Что, ответ вас не устраивает? А это единственно верное решение для общего случая.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужен [`Matcher#find()`](http://www.javenue.info/post/43#regex-search):

```
String line = "101@ext-local       : SIP/101,CustomPresen  State:Idle            Presence:not_set         Watchers  0";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+/\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Так как нужно только первое совпадение, `while` можно заменить на `if`.

Comment: Для данного примера согласен, просто написал общее решение